# How to replace multiple occurrences of a letter with that letter?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, expression

I have a file with 5 columns that looks like this:

```
15642 G A.aa,, 0.77501 107
15643 G A.a,.A, 0.7570 17
15644 C t.TtTt,.T, 0.7501 10
```

I'm trying to convert the 3rd column of Aa's and Tt's to just "A" or "T". 
Output:

```
15642 G A 0.77501 107
15643 G A 0.7570 17
15644 C T 0.7501 10
```

I've tried various awk methods without success. I'd sincerely appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '$3~/[Aa]/{$3="A"} $3~/[Tt]/{$3="T"} 1'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

There's many possibilities including:

```
$ awk '{sub(/\..*/,"",$3)} 1' file
15642 G A 0.77501 107
15643 G A 0.7570 17
15644 C t 0.7501 10
```

or

```
$ awk '{$3=substr($3,1,1)} 1' file
15642 G A 0.77501 107
15643 G A 0.7570 17
15644 C t 0.7501 10
```

or

```
$ awk '{$3=toupper(substr($3,1,1))} 1' file
15642 G A 0.77501 107
15643 G A 0.7570 17
15644 C T 0.7501 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/(\S)\S*/\U\1/3' file
```

Convert the first character of the third field to uppercase.